# python: can't open file 'python2': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

im trying to run my docker-compose and I keep getting this error whenever running docker-compose up
This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
ADD . /todo
WORKDIR /todo
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My docker-compose:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python2 -u app.py
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
      #volumes:
      # - .:/todo
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo:3.0.2
```

~
any help would be greatly appreciated I've been stuck on this for a while!

Comment: try changing `python2` to `python` in the command

Comment: You're using one of the `python3` docker images but the `web` service command is trying to execute `python2`. Which doesn't exist in that image. Nor should you try to use it (deprecated).

Comment: `python2` is available in the `python:3.7` image: `docker run -ti --rm python:3.7 python2 --version` => `Python 2.7.16`

Comment: Are you using a windows or a linux container?

Comment: I've tried changing python2 to python but it comes up with the same error except its just python. I also tried changing the command to python3 and keeping the Dockerfile to python3 but I still get the same errno2 that there is no such file or directory. I am also using a linux container

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
Make sure that you dump your containers and images before running docker-compose up and the error should go away.